# plotting an inequality

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

Can anyone help in plot an inequallity

Abs[[x/[1 + x]] - [y/[1 + y]]] <= Abs[x - y]/[1 + 0.01 Abs[x - y]] where 0 < x< 1 and 0 < y< 1

When I tried with Plot command as well as Plot3D command, it is not displaying the output.

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code! Squared  brackets are reserved for Mathematica functions

Comment: Probably `RegionPlot` is the function you're looking for.

Comment: Square brackets are used for functions, for grouping use round brackets. Further, I think the inequality is true over the whole region.

Comment: Actually I used  simple brackets ( ) for the quantity in Denominator and I know that the inequality is true in the entire region (anlaytically) but I want to establish the same graphically.

Answer (score 3):

For establishing the truth of the inequality over the entire region,

```
Refine[Abs[x/(1 + x)] - y/(1 + y) <= Abs[x - y]/(1 + 1/100 Abs[x - y]), 
       0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1]
(*    True    *)
```

For plotting the same,

```
RegionPlot[Abs[x/(1 + x)] - y/(1 + y) <= Abs[x - y]/(1 + 0.01 Abs[x - y]),
           {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```